# How to make a clean toString for multiple 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, string, tostring

I have an ArrayList which contains some object which has an attribute called grid which is 2 dimensional array filled with numbers.

I want to print the grids next to each other like a "big grid of grid", separated by a character, not line by line and there should be maximum 6 arrays next to each others.
I've tried to print the rows of the first 6 arrays one by one then I go to the next line but i'm getting lost and it's not working properly.

I'm trying to have this

[image]

but like this

[image]

So far, this is what i've done:

```
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < square.size(); i++) {

        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                

                if(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j] >= 10){
                    if(j == 0){
                        s+="| "+String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j])+" ";
                    }
                    if(j == 4){
                        s+=String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j])+" |";
                    }
                    if(j!= 0 && j !=4){
                        s+=String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j])+" ";
                    }
                }

                else{
                    if(j == 0){
                        s+="| "+String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j])+"  ";
                    }
                    if(j == 4){
                        s+=String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j])+"  |";
                    }
                    if(j!= 0 && j !=4){
                        s+=String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j])+"  ";
                    }
                }

            }
            count++;

            if(count == 6){
                count = 0;
                s += "\n";
            }
        }


    }

    return s;
```

The counter is for the number of array I want next to each others.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Print to what? How large are these 2D Arrays? Do all these 2D Arrays contain the same number of rows and columns? How many columns of Array blocks do you want to print as a row? What else needs to be printed with these Array Blocks? What have you tried and what are you having problems with your attempt?

Comment: Can you show us a small example of what your input is, and what you expect the output to look like. Also, show the code you have tried, and explain what part you are stuck on. Hint: To print several grids side by side you simply need to make lots of long lines for example in the simplest format `String rowToPrint = rowToPrint + "   " + yourList.get(item).getGrid()[0];`

Comment: These are 5 by 5 arrays which are already filled with number i'm just struggling with printing what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to construct display line by line as iterate through lists.
Eg: `Line1 = List1Line1 + List2Line1 + etc`
Used an auxiliary list:`result` to keep Lines (mainly each ordered elements).

Test Lists are populated with dummy values so each list contains elements from `1-25` in random order. Simple output check is to inspect elements from individual lists to see if all fulfill a group `1-25`.

```
public class TestArrayPrint {

    static List<Integer>[] list =  new ArrayList[5];
    static List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //dummy values 
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
        {
            list[i] = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 25).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.shuffle(list[i]);
        }
        //populate list[0] from array
    
        int dummy_arr[][] = {{1,2,3,4,5},
                             {6,7,8,9,10},
                             {11,12,13,14,15},
                             {16,17,18,19,20},
                             {21,22,23,24,25}};
        list[0].clear();
        for(int i=0;i<dummy_arr.length;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<dummy_arr[i].length;j++)
            {
                list[0].add(dummy_arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        //full scan
        for(int k=0;k<list.length;k++)
        {
            //next line
            for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
            {
                //add first line from first list, then first line from second list, etc
                for(int j=0;j<list.length;j++)
                {
                    //covert to 2 string digits for display 
                    String s= (list[i].get(0)<10) ? " "+list[i].get(0) : list[i].get(0).toString() ;
                    list[i].remove(0);
                    //elements will be in order 
                    //Line1List1 Line1List2 ...
                    //Line2List1 Line2List2 ...
                    result.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        //result.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Ordered Elements to Display="+result.size()+"\n");
        
        //display
        //just adapt i,j,k for various matrix sizes
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
                {
                    if(k==0)
                    {
                        line.append("| "+result.get(0));
                        result.remove(0);
                    }
                    else if(k==4)
                    {
                        line.append(" "+result.get(0)+" |");
                        result.remove(0);
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                        line.append(" "+result.get(0));
                        result.remove(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }   
    }
}
```

Output

```
Ordered Elements to Display=125

| 11 12  5 13 15 ||  1 24 19 22 13 ||  6  9  8  3 13 || 18  3 10 14  2 || 19 21  3 23 18 |
| 20 24 21  3  7 || 12 14  7  8 16 || 11  4 23  1  5 ||  6  8 13 23 15 || 20 12  7 13  6 |
|  8 18  1 25  2 ||  9  3  2 25 17 || 12 17 21 20 16 || 12 24 17 20 22 || 10  1 16 15  8 |
| 23 22  4 17 16 || 10 21 18  4 11 || 25 24 14 22  2 ||  7  4  5  9 19 ||  9  5 14 11  2 |
|  9 10 19 14  6 || 23 15  5 20  6 || 18 10  7 19 15 || 11 16 21  1 25 || 24 17 25 22  4 |
```

Note: Is irrelevant if your list have methods to get a specific element, the mechanism should be something similar (remove processed element could be useful even for your logic). On my example elements flows in lines so `element(6) : list.get(5)` is `list.grid(1,0)`.

Comment: It works perfectly as intended but how do I convert my `int[] []` into the `List<Integer>[]`.

Comment: check code example, now elements from first list will be from 1-25 in natural order. Etc.

Comment: Ok, it works for 5 arrays but what if i want more than 5 arrays to be printed, like 100 ? I need 20 line of this but how ?

Comment: As suggested in this answer, you just need to change the loops to use the actual values, for example, instead of using `i<5` in this loop `for(int i=0;i<5;i++)` you should use the actual length, for example `i<yourList.length` like this `for(int i=0;i<yourList.length;i++)` or to match the ode in your question use `square.size()` in the loop instead.

Comment: Think what is to be changed in order to work with any custom `array[m,n]`?  Maybe loops should be iterate through `[m,n]`. See also where `array` is used, maybe on `list`. Said on code : `just adapt i,j,k for various matrix sizes`, so maybe figure out that `all 3 params could be taken from your custom structure`. Hint: Inspect one more time how `list[0]` is initialize with  `arr[5][5]`. Kindly check also @sorifiend comments. It will be nice if you could figure out by yourself what to change in order to get the desired output. At least try and if issues you were welcome to add a new post.

Comment: Yep, I tried both of your code, it works and it was really useful. I have understand how your code works now. I made some tweaks and it works thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are most of the way there, we just need to construct each individual line as we go which we can do by modifying your existing code a little to use a list of strings that we can append as we go rather than a single string that is going to be a pain to format. We can combine and return the single string at the end instead:

```
//Create a list of lines to print so that we can append to the end of each line as we go
ArrayList<String> linesToPrint = new ArrayList<>();

//Populate the list with blank strings
for (int i = 0; i < square.size(); i++)
{
    linesToPrint.add("");
}

//Loop through the list of squares
for (int i = 0; i < square.size(); i++)
{
    //Put the count inside the loop so it resets every time
    int count = 0;
    //loop throughthe rows
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
    //Create a blank string to store the current grid row
    String row = "";
    //loop through the columns
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        //Format double didgits
        if (square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j] >= 10)
        {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            row += "| " + String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j]) + " ";
        }
        if (j == 4)
        {
            row += String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j]) + " |";
        }
        if (j != 0 && j != 4)
        {
            row += String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j]) + " ";
        }
        }
        //Format single didgets
        else
        {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            row += "| " + String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j]) + "  ";
        }
        if (j == 4)
        {
            row += String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j]) + "  |";
        }
        if (j != 0 && j != 4)
        {
            row += String.valueOf(square.get(i).getGrid()[k][j]) + "  ";
        }
        }
    }
    
    //Once the row has been created store it in the list
    linesToPrint.set(count, (linesToPrint.get(count)) + row);
    count++;
    }
}

//Construct the complete string
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < square.size(); i++)
{
    s += linesToPrint.get(i) +"\r\n";
}
return s;
```

Now the returned string should work as desired.

Note that this will only display correctly when using a console with a monospaced font.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how could I make it so it works with all console ?

Comment: The windows console and most IDE are configured to use a monospaced font by default, so you can ignore that final note in most cases, it was just a general comment unrelated to the code.